# Is it bad practice to use dependency injection to create a singleton object that can then be used throughout the app in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, software-design

So imagine I have an object User like so:

```
class User {
  var id: Int
  var name: String
  var phone: String
}
```

And some service that gets the details like so:

```
protocol UserService {
  func getUser(withID id: Int, completion: @escaping(_ user: User, _ error: Error) -> Void)
}
```

and then an API Service

```
class UserAPIService: UserService {
  func getUser(withID id: Int, completion: @escaping(_ user: User, _ error: Error) -> Void) {
    // GET USER FROM API HERE
  }
}
```

And a service for testing

```
class UserTestService: UserService {
  func getUser(withID id: Int, completion: @escaping(_ user: User, _ error: Error) -> Void) {
    // RETURN SOME TEST USER HERE
  }
}
```

Now the obvious implementation here is in any class that requires the service in the app you create a UserAPIService object and inject it in to use. And then in testing you create the UserTestService and inject it in to use.

So this means (for my use case), that every ViewModal which hits this function, I need to create and inject in the service. Now that is fine, and it seems to be the practice that I see everywhere, but my question is, why not create a singleton on app/test start so that I don't have to inject it everywhere? For example, create a singleton instance of the UserService like so:

```
fileprivate _current: UserService?

class UserServiceManager {
  static var current: UserService {
    get {
      if let c = _current { return c }
      return UserAPIService() //return some default if not set
    }
    set {
      _current = newVal
    }
  }
}
```

Then we can set the required usage in either the App Delegates `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` or Tests `setUpWithError` like so:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
  UserServiceManager.current = UserAPIService()
  return true
}
```

and

```
override func setUpWithError() throws {
  UserServiceManager.current = UserTestService()
}
```

Now everywhere I use it, I don't need to inject it, I can just use the `UserServiceManager.current` request. Is this bad practice? And if so, why? It seems like a more DRY version. My only concern I can see this far is that if I decide to split my code into modules, then I will have to import each module into the AppDelegate.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use the same object for every injection, then you don't need injection in the first place.

If you are not going to use the same object for every injection, then a singleton is a poor choice for generating runtime objects, because

1. being static, no access to any runtime properties
2. only one instance at a time, when you expect many runtime variations
3. problems with singletons in general, you have no way to track who mutates it from where.

From your use case here, I'd say create the service as a singleton, then you can remove all injection.

There are libraries that build around singleton for complex dependencies, which imo are over-generalization. For example, I never need to inject network service to anything. Why made complex dependencies in the first place?

So yes, I think singleton for dependency injection is a bad practice. For other purpose, depends on usage.

Comment: I guess from my question, the consideration I make for "If you are going to use the same object for every injection" is sort of. For example, I use the UserAPIService for every User request in the app, but I don't use it for testing. So in this case, I do always use the same object, but only for that particular module